# Android layout_toLeftOf not working

Tags: android

I've searched quite a lot here and have tried to provide information about how to align the children objects inside my relative layout, however one of them doesn't display.

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView1"
   android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="example"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView2"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textView2"
         android:text="example" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

TextView3 doesn't appear at all. It looks like there is a missing or conflicting rule, but I can't figure out which one.

Comment: Checkout my solution below, works for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and give this a try, works for me.

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="example"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
         android:text="example"
          />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I meant to say toRightOf and not toLeftOf... I should have also explained what I was trying to accomplish. A lot of answers make sense, this one happened to "guess" what I was aiming for!

Answer (score 1):

textView2 is aligned to the left. If you align textView3 to the left of a left object it's going to be off the screen

Comment: Whizzle is right. If anything, put textView3 first then align textView2 to the right of textView3

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense, but indeed it was my mistake as I actually wanted to align textView3 toRightOf textView2...

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not provide the code for textView1, but if I were to assume that your textView1 were to be on the top left side of the screen, then if you have this line for your inner RelativeLayout:

> android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView1"

textView2 would be aligned to textView1, therefore if you added textView3 was added and you did:

> android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView2"

then it would appear off the screen to the left.

Answer (score 0):

What I watch here for example using Relative Layout ,you need to be specific, if you wish to locate to the right of editTextNumberPeriods in this case, also you need to instruct .xml where is textView2, in this case it is below btn18, I meant it is not enough to instruct .xml if it is right or left. I tested it, it works perfectly.

```
 <TextView
        **android:id="@+id/btn18"**
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn19"
        android:text="Please enter numbers of periods." />


<EditText
    **`android:id="@+id/editTextNumberPeriods"`**
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn18"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#68DBFA"
    android:hint="numbers of periods"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#7C1616" />


 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        **android:layout_below="@id/btn18"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editTextNumberPeriods"**
        android:text="TextView" />
```